# How to retrieve and display image base on URL and Product-ID?

Tags: php

I re post my code here..
Am keep getting the error of :

```
Notice: Undefined index: Image URL in C:\wamp\www\mySql1.php on line 35..
```

my URL value in the pimage table is : `'c:\wamp\www\toy1.jpg'`. May i know is this correct?? Really appreciate anyone kind response and help..

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
//open connection to MySQL Server
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '')
        or die ('Unable to connect to !');

// select database for use
mysql_select_db('we-toys') or die ('Unable to select database!');

$query = 'select * from product p, pimage p2 where p.pid=p2.imagepid';
$result = mysql_query($query)
        or die ('Error in query: $query. ' . mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo '<table width = 100% cellpadding = 10 cellspacing = 0 border = 1>';
    echo '<tr><td><b>ID</b></td>
      <td><b>PName</b></td>
      <td><b>PGroup</b></td>
          <td><b>PType</‌​b></td>
          <td><b>Qty</b></td>
          <td><b>Image></b></td>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    { echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[5].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[6].'</td>
    <td><img src="'.$row['ImageURL'].'"></td>
    </tr>'; 
} 
echo '</table>'; 

}
        else
        {
            echo 'No rows found!';        
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($connection);
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in that case just use this
<img src="'.$row['ImageURL'].'">

Comment: if it not works make one folder in C:\wamp\www and save all your files and images in this folder then try
 <img src="'.$row['ImageURL'].'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo '<table width = 100% cellpadding = 10 cellspacing = 0 border = 1>
<tr><td><b>ID</b></td>
<td><b>PName</b></td>
<td><b>PGroup</b></td>
<td><b>PType</‌​b></td>
<td><b>Qty</b></td>
<td><b>Image></b>
</td></tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ echo '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td>
<td>'.$row[2].'</td>
<td>'.$row[4].'</td>
<td>'.$row[5].'</td>
<td>'.$row[6].'</td>
<td><img src="'.$row['ImageURL'].'"></td></tr>'; } 
echo '</table>'; ?>
```

Comment: So Sorry sir.. I make myself statement confuse to you.. I actually would like to ask how to retrieve the image from the destinated folder and display it in php code.. not the join query.. so sorry..

Comment: <img src="foldername/'.$row['imageurl'].'">

Comment: sir.. i hv this below error :  Undefined index: ImageURL in C:\wamp\www\mySql1.php on line 35.. my url value is : "C:wamp\www\toy1.jpg". Is this correct?

Comment: i apply ur code given above : echo '<img src="foldername/'.$row['ImageURL'].'">';  Is this right?? thank you very much..

Comment: // select database for use
mysql_select_db('we-toys') or die ('Unable to select database!');

$query = 'select * from product p, pimage p2 where p.pid=p2.imagepid';
$result = mysql_query($query)
        or die ('Error in query: $query. ' . mysql_error());

Comment: if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 echo '<table width = 100% cellpadding = 10 cellspacing = 0 border = 1'; 
    echo '<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>PName</b></td><td><b>PGroup</b></td><td><b>PType</b></td>
          <td><b>Qty</b></td><td><b>Image></b></td> '; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[0] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[2] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[4] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[5] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[6] .'</td>';
echo '<img src=.$row['ImageURL'].'</td>';   }
    echo '</table>';}

Comment: @user2649074 the code should be in your question not in comments, click edit and add it there

Comment: Sorry sir.. i edit my post with codes you guided me.. but still do not work.. am so sorry..

Comment: in which folder are you uploading your images?..give the path..
<img src="path here/'.$row['ImageURL'].'">

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_row

Comment: close the first <tr> with </tr>

Comment: really thank you sir..no error when used mysql_fetch_array, but no image displayed.. i changed value of url in db to 'toy1.jpg'. and html code to :<td><img src="C:\wamp\www\'.$row['ImageURL'].'"></td>. But encountered error as :syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\mysql2.php on line 36.. I am really new in html sir..

Comment: in the first place sir.. what shall i store in the imageurl field? just 'toy1.jpg' or whole path as 'C:\wamp\www\toy1.png' ?

Comment: tell me the destination folder of your image toy1.jpg
and just stored the image name in the imageurl field

Comment: sir.. the destination folder of my image toy1.jpg is in C:\wamp\www. really thank you.. sorry for troubling you..

Comment: in that case just use this
<img src="'.$row['ImageURL'].'">

Comment: if you satisfied then click on the tick mark on the left side of my answer :-)